# Is this a different proof of the fundamental group being abelian?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fundamental-groups

I have proved the fundamental group of a **topological group** is abelian. But I've found nowhere the similar proof as mine. Everywhere I looked up, it was done either exploiting categorical properties or something like taking product of two paths.

My proof goes as follows:

Let $a$ and $b$ be two loops in a topological group $(G,\bullet )$ starting at the identity element $e$. We need to show $ a\ast b \simeq b\ast a$, where "$\ast$" is the fundamental group operation.

Now for each $t,s\in [0,1]$, define

$F_t(s)=a(st)\ast(a(t)\bullet b(s))\ast \bar a(st)$

Now {$F_t$} gives the homotopy between $b$ and $a\ast b \ast \bar a$.

> The main idea is at each time $t$, we first go to $a(t)$ along $a$ and then traverse the translated path $a(t)\bullet b$ and then return back along the inverse path of the first one. Continuity of $F$ follows from pasting lemma.

This proof seems correct but why do other proofs avoid this straightforward argument?

Comment: The proof I know of goes as follows : $G$ be a top. group, then there is a multiplication $G \times G \to G$ and an inverse $G \to G$. This gives $\pi_1$-level maps $\pi_1(G) \times \pi_1(G) \to \pi_1(G)$ and $\pi_1(G) \to \pi_1(G)$. So $\pi_1(G)$ gets a natural abelian group structure from the top group structure of $G$: so all we need to do is to show that this group structure agrees with the group structure on $\pi_1(G)$ coming from the definition. This is where Eckmann-Hilton argument kicks in. [continued]

Comment: So while I agree your proof is neater, the proof I mentioned seems conceptually much more natural to me. Perhaps others also feel this is more natural, thus most textbooks introduce this?

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is very nice, but the definition
$$F_t(s)=a(st)\ast(a(t)\bullet b(s))\ast \bar a(st)$$
is inadequate because $a(st)$, $a(t)\bullet b(s))$, $\bar a(st)$ are single points of $G$ which cannot be composed by $*$ which is the *succession of paths*. What you mean is
$$F_t = a_t * (a(t) \bullet b) * \overline{a_t}$$
where $a_t(s) = a(st), \overline{a_t}(s) = a_t(1-s) = a((1-s)t)$. Note that $\overline{a_t}$ is the inverse of $a_t$, not part of the inverse $\bar a$ of $a$. In fact, $a((1-s)t) \ne  a(1-st) = \overline{a}(st)$. Explicitly you can also write
$$F_t(s) =  \begin{cases} a(3st) & 0 \le s \le 1/3 \\ a(t) \bullet b(3s - 1) & 1/3 \le s \le 2/3 \\  a((3(1-s)t)  & 2/3 \le s \le 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes you are right. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

I really like your argument. [This one](http://www.woflmao.net/publications/abelianFundamentalGroup.pdf) I found uses the same idea, but it is neither as concise, nor as clear as yours. [This proof](https://hilbertthm90.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/lie-groups-have-abelian-fundamental-group/) is also pretty short, but the argument is a lot more subtle, and it took me a while to see what is happening. Finally, [these notes](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/somnath/Notes/GSS5.pdf) describe the ideas of your proof without a formal proof. After reading these, I think that most authors are writing for an audience experienced enough that either (a) the readers are expected to fill in the details equivalent to your proof themselves, or (b) they would consider more subtle arguments just as easy.

Comment: Alex, all of these links talk about Lie groups. But a topological group, in general, need not have a smooth structure. [FWIW: Having taken a course in Lie theory this semester that I was decidedly unprepared for, I think that when the audience is at the level to understand Lie groups, I think both (a) and (b) are factors.]

Comment: More background is in my  paper with Chris Spencer , ``$\cal G$-groupoids, crossed modules and the  fundamental groupoid of a topological group'', _Proc Kon. Ned. Akad. v.  Wet_. 7 (1976) 296-302, available from my publication list.

Comment: I know this is 4 years after, but the homotopy you have defined is not a based homotopy of loops, meaning F_t(0)=a(t) and not equal to e @paladin