# A question about the proof of $\pi_1(G,e)$ being abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, abelian-groups, fundamental-groups

I have seen a lot of posts dealing with the fundamental group over a topological group. In almost every proof I’ve seen of it being abelian, we need to show that if I have two paths $\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$ based at e, the identity of G, then

$\gamma_1(s)*\gamma_2(s) \cong (\gamma_1 \circ \gamma_2)(s)$

where $\circ $ denotes concatenation, $*$ denotes the product from the group, and $\cong$ denotes path homotopy equivalence. None of the solutions I’ve seen show how to prove this homotopy equivalence. Even things like the Eckmann-Hilton argument seem to be taking this for granted. Is there some trivial homotopy that I’m just not seeing? If so, what is it?

Comment: This is a *consequence* of the Eckmann-Hilton argument. Its hypothesis is the common identity element and interchangeability: $(\gamma_1*\gamma_2)\circ(\gamma_3*\gamma_4)\cong (\gamma_1\circ\gamma_3)*(\gamma_2\circ\gamma_4)$.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3979932/591889

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fundamental group of a topological group: Inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979922/fundamental-group-of-a-topological-group-inversion)

Comment: These do not quite answer my question. How do we know that $(\gamma_1\circ c_{e}) * (\gamma_2 \circ c_{e}) \cong \gamma_1*\gamma_2$? Here $c_e$ is the constant loop at the identity. This question seems trivial, but constructing that homotopy would be difficult.

Comment: The loop $c_e$ represents the neutral element in $\pi_1(G, e)$.

Comment: Here is a nice alternative proof that $\pi_1(G,e)$ is abelian: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1713887. But it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Qi Zhu even with that fact, aren’t we still assuming that if $\gamma_1 \cong \gamma_2$, then $\gamma_1*\gamma_3\cong \gamma_2*\gamma_3$?

Comment: @Paul Frost The problem with that solution is that the homotopy they provided is not a based homotopy.

Comment: Take a homotopy $H$ realizing $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2$. Concatenating this homotopy with the constant homotopy yields a homotopy $\gamma_1 * \gamma_3 \simeq \gamma_2 * \gamma_3$.

Comment: I would recommend revisiting the first principles of homotopies. You need to understand that $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2$ implies $\gamma_1 * \gamma_3 \simeq \gamma_2 * \gamma_3$ if you want to understand that the operation in $\pi_1$ is well-defined.

Comment: Oh I see. If $H$ is a based homotopy realizing $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2$, then $H*\gamma_3$ would be a based homotopy realizing $\gamma_1*\gamma_3\simeq \gamma_2 * \gamma_3$

Comment: @slowspider It is based. Check the definition for $s=0,1 $.

Comment: @PaulFrost Shoot, you're right!

Comment: @Berci The Eckmann-Hilton argument applies to show commutavity. But you have to prove the interchangability of both operations. This is not for free.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I = [0,1]$ and $K = I \times \{0\} \cup \{1\} \times I \subset I^2 = I \times I$ and let $i : K \hookrightarrow I^2$ denote the inclusion map. Define

1. $u : I \to K, u(t) = (2t,0)$ for $t \le 1/2$ and $u(t) = (1,2t-1)$ for $t \ge 1/2$.
2. $\gamma_{12} : K \to G, \gamma_{12}(x,0) = \gamma_1(x), \gamma_{12}(1,y) = \gamma_2(y)$.
3. $\Delta : I \to I^2, \Delta(t) = (t,t)$. This is the diagonal map.
4. $\Gamma : I^2 \to G, \Gamma(x,y) = \gamma_1(x) * \gamma_2(y)$.

These are continuous maps; clearly $\gamma_1 \circ \gamma_2 = \gamma_{12} u$ and $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2 = \Gamma \Delta$. Moreover we have
$$\Gamma i = \gamma_{12} .$$
In fact, $\Gamma i(x,0) = \Gamma(x,0) = \gamma_1(x) * \gamma_2(0) = \gamma_1(x) * e = \gamma_1(x) =  \gamma_{12}(x,0)$ and $\Gamma i(1,y) = \Gamma(1,y) = \gamma_1(1) * \gamma_2(y) = e * \gamma_2(y) = \gamma_2(y) =  \gamma_{12}(1,y0)$.

Therefore $\gamma_1 \circ \gamma_2 = \gamma_{12} u = \Gamma i u$. But the paths $iu : I \to I^2$ and $\Delta : I \to I^2$ are homotopic via
$$H :  I \times I \to I^2, H(t,s) = s\Delta(t) + (1-s) iu (t) = \begin{cases} (2t -st),st) & t \le 1/2  \\(st+1-s,2t -st +s -1) & t \ge 1/2 \end{cases}.$$
Hence $\bar H  = \Gamma H : I \times I \to G$ is a homotopy between the paths $\gamma_1 \circ \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2$. Explicitly we have
$$\bar H(t,s) = \begin{cases} \gamma_1(2t -st) * \gamma_2(st ) & t \le 1/2  \\ \gamma_1(st+1-s) * \gamma_2(2t -st +s -1) & t \ge 1/2 \end{cases}$$

The above construction is an adaption of the approach in [A confusion on $\Omega$ and $\Sigma$ functors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075980).